# (correct ?) restfull uri's

Tags: api, rest, routes

After a bit of reading, I think I get what the whole RESTfull thing is about. That being said, in my reading I've seen a couple different ways of structuring the URI's.

**Collection**: `/user` or `/user/`

**Element**: `/user/123` or `/user?id=123`

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_services) uses `/user` + `/user/123`, but Wikipedia clearly isn't the master source.

My personal thoughts were that going with `/user/` + `/user/123` or `/user` + `/user?id=123` made a little more sense since you immediately know if the resource operating on is a collection or element.

Perhaps what I'm asking is, are any of these URI combinations the *wrong* way to go about it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some would argue it's a matter of personal preference, but many feel that using plural names for collections is strictly better than singular - `/users` vs `/user`. If the "id" is the unique identifier for the user, then it's traditional for that to be a full resource endpoint - `/users/123`, not `/users?id=123`. On the other hand, if you want all users whose name is "Bob", then you would do `/users?firstName=Bob`.